# E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/stretch/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP:x.x.x.x]

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt

I am using Ubuntu1804.

When I do `apt update`, I got an error

> E: Failed to fetch
> https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/stretch/InRelease  403  Forbidden
> [IP: x.x.x.x 443]
>
> E: The repository
> 'https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease' is no longer signed.
>
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
> therefore disabled by default.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for
> repository creation and user configuration details.

When I do `apt upgrade`, I got an error

> Err:1 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 php-xdebug
> amd64 3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+0~20220625.46+debian9~1.gbp6966da 404  Not Found [IP: 139.99.63.197 443]
>
> Err:2 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 php8.1-xdebug amd64
> 3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+0~20220625.46+debian9~1.gbp6966da   404  Not Found [IP: 139.99.63.197 443]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> [https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/x/xdebug/php-xdebug_3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+0~20220625.46+debian9~1.gbp6966da_amd64.deb](https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/x/xdebug/php-xdebug_3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+0%7E20220625.46+debian9%7E1.gbp6966da_amd64.deb)  404  Not Found [IP: 139.99.63.197 443]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> [https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/x/xdebug/php8.1-xdebug_3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+0~20220625.46+debian9~1.gbp6966da_amd64.deb](https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/x/xdebug/php8.1-xdebug_3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+0%7E20220625.46+debian9%7E1.gbp6966da_amd64.deb)  404  Not Found [IP: 139.99.63.197 443]
>
> E: Unable to fetch some
> archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt, I fixed the problem by executing the following commands:

```
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl
curl -sSLo /usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

This posts explain it all:

https://lowendtalk.com/discussion/180271/the-repository-https-packages-sury-org-php-stretch-release-does-no-longer-have-a-release-file

In short:

- debian 9 stretch is EOL
- Sury has no support for it anymore
- update to debian 10 or 11 is recommended

Comment: That is not an answer to the question of updating D9.  EOL or not some people don't have the option of upgrading the OS

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. If somebody hasn't the option of update their OS, those people must use old versions of php

Comment: Same issues on debian 10, so not relevant to it

Answer (score 1):

For older Debian version like stretch, I solved it by adding this repository

```
deb http://mirror-bbg-5.internet1.de/sury-php-stretch stretch main
```

in the following file

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

Then added the repository key

```
wget -qO - https://debian.octopuce.fr/sury-php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
apt update
apt install php8.1
```